# Is there a type of extension cord I can use with a gutter heater?

Tags: electrical, heater, gutters, extension-cord

I just purchased a gutter heater (yes I know it may not actually work), and the user's manual said not to use an extension cord. We don't have any outlets within the 6 foot range of the cord on the heating cable.

Is there not a specification of extension cord that could be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your place, I would try to find the shortest length (25' maybe) of gauge 12.

Comment: cord should be sized for the current *and* rated for outdoor use.

Comment: You can also fab exactly the cord you want using *cordage* or by truncating an extension cord of correct rated cordage, gauge and condition.

Comment: 12 awg cord would be fine even at 50'. All the tape style heaters I have seen are rated for use on a 15 amp circuit, cords are rated differently than house wiring so in reality a 14 gauge cord will be sufficient in size.FWIW The failure point on most cords is the ends, not the conductors.